# How to save datepicker date as mongodb date?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

In a meteor app I select a date via jquery datepicker, this is triggered by 
**click .tododateDue**. After providing all information in my dialog all fields of the todo are saved via **click .saveTodo**

I like to display the date in my input field as dd.mm.yy but I need to save it in a mongodb collection as 'date'.

Since I use **todo.datedue = tmpl.find('.tododateDue').value;** to save the date I get a String in my collection.

How can I save this date as the type 'date' in the mongodb collection?

```
Template.todoDlg.events({
'click .saveTodo':function(evt,tmpl){
   console.log('tmpl',tmpl);
   var todo = {};
   todo.note = tmpl.find('.todoitem').value;
   todo.title = tmpl.find('.todotitle').value;
   todo.datedue = tmpl.find('.tododateDue').value;
   todo.project = Session.get('active_project');
   Meteor.call('addTodo',todo);
   Session.set('adding_todo',false);
 },

'click .tododateDue': function (evt, tmpl) {
    Meteor.setTimeout(function () {
        $('.tododateDue').datepicker({
            onSelect: function (dateText) {
                console.log('date',tmpl.find('.tododateDue').value);
                //Meteor.call('updateProjectDate', Session.get('active_project'), dateText);
            },
            dateFormat:'dd.mm.yy'
        });
    }, 100)
 }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you can use `moment.js`:

```
 todo.datedue = moment(tmpl.find('.tododateDue').value, "dd.mm.yy").toDate();
```

It will return Date-object...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps autoform would help you here.
http://autoform.meteor.com/types